# How to make a inner div width fit text when outer div fixed width and scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, text, width

### Html

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>text</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Css

```
.outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: scroll;
}

li {
    margin: 5px;
}

li>div {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #369;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf9xk/1/)

**Need:**

Inner div width fit with text. And text just single line. And inner div don't use fixed width.

Like this(this demo LI's margin not work.)
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/gf9xk/19/)

Comment: Do you need to show this only in one line?

Comment: UPDATE2:I want:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf9xk/16/) but inner div not fixed width.

Comment: So you want all the inner div's to be of same width inside the outer div showing the text's in a single line?

Comment: @venkateshwar yes,a single line. I'm sorry, I just don't see your comment.

Comment: check my [answer's link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12560722/1577396). Hope you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

```
float:left;
margin:5px;
```

in li>div style

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/gf9xk/19/)

or [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/gf9xk/22/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>text</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: scroll;
}

li {
    margin: 5px;
}

li>div {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    width:400px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #369;
    background-color: #fff;

}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/gf9xk/20/).

If you dont want to break the text then you can use `overflow-x:scroll` property

Comment: inner div don't use fixed width.

Comment: Please specify your question clearly. Edit your question and make it understand. So that we can answer it. @consatan

Comment: I'm sorry, blame my expression is not clear. Thanks a lot!!(And I'm sorry my English...)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to

```
word-break: break-all;
```

.....

```
li>div {
    word-break: break-all; // add this line
    height:30px; // remove this line
}
```

and **remove** `height` in your `li>div`

***[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gf9xk/8/)***

**HTML from the Demo**

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>text</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS from the Demo**

```
.outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: scroll;
}

li {
    margin: 5px;
}

li>div {
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #369;
    background-color: #fff;
     word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want break text.